# Insert triples in a graph using SPARQLWrapper

Tags: python, sparql, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to insert triples in a graph using below SPARQL query:

```
for s, p, o in g:
    id = s
    rel = p
    med = o
    
    queryString = """ 
                    PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
                    
                    INSERT DATA {
                    GRAPH <http://example.org/mapping> 
                    { %s skos:%s %s }} 
                    
                  """ %(id, rel, med)
    
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://blazegraph/namespace/HC2/sparql/update")
    sparql.setQuery(queryString)
    sparql.method = 'POST'
    sparql.query()
```

However, when I try to run this, I get below error:

```
QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: A bad request has been sent to the endpoint: probably the SPARQL query is badly formed.
```

I am not able to figure out what is the error in the above code.

Comment: What's the resulting `queryString`? It was wrong.

Comment: http://example.org/mapping/619325 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#broadMatch http://example.org/mapping/10083941

Comment: These are the s,p,o I am trying to insert in the graph

Comment: full URIs have to be put into angle brackets, did your check your query string being generated with string interpolation? `%s` to `<%s>` (similar for `?o` if it'S a URI, for literals of course more tricky depending on the datatype)